# Issues with leaflet map

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am trying to implement a leaflet map API but I cant get it to show up. I am following this link.
https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/streets/leaflet?utm_campaign=2018-12%20%7C%20leaflet%20series&utm_content=leaflet%20tutorial%201&utm_medium=social&utm_source=youtube&utm_term=desclink-leaflet-sample
[image: Picture of issue]

My code
map.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
      <a href="https://www.maptiler.com" style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:10px;z-index:999;"><img src="https://api.maptiler.com/resources/logo.svg" alt="MapTiler logo"></a>
    </div>
    <p><a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a></p>
    <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);
      L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=cCaw1Q6a8s1Bm4tJPpTq',{
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        minZoom: 1,
        attribution: "\u003ca href=\"https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; MapTiler\u003c/a\u003e \u003ca href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; OpenStreetMap contributors\u003c/a\u003e",
        crossOrigin: true
      }).addTo(map);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

map.component.css

```
html { height:100%; }
body { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" 
content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />
    <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
      <a href="https://www.maptiler.com" 
style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:10px;z-index:999;"><img 
src="https://api.maptiler.com/resources/logo.svg" alt="MapTiler logo"></a>
    </div>
    <p><a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" 
target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a 
href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; 
OpenStreetMap contributors</a></p>
    <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);
      
L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=cCaw1Q6a8s1Bm4tJPpTq',{
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        minZoom: 1,
        attribution: "\u003ca href=\"https://www.maptiler.com/copyright" /
        "target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; MapTiler\u003c/a\u003e \u003ca" /
        "href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" /
        "target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; OpenStreetMap" /
        "contributors\u003c/a\u003e",
        crossOrigin: true
      }).addTo(map);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

your titleLayer had \n character.

[here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhpoq8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

if you want to work with leaflet in angular the best solution is using angular version of leaflet.

Comment: I tried this and it still does not show up

Comment: did you try out this code on your end and it worked?

Comment: i added a stackblitz project or my answer.

Comment: thank you so much I managed to make it work :)